# Copy files according the filename containing a future date in a specific format

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date, cp

I have these files, for example:

```
20029181109173105_MAN_TDR.PLU
20029181109185001_MAN_TDR.PLU
20029181109185301_MAN_TDR.PLU
20029181109185601_MAN_TDR.PLU
20029181109185901_MAN_TDR.PLU
```

I need to copy the files that have in their names the date format that is greater than the current date, for this case it is "181109180000" (11th November, 2018 18:00h GMT-5).

Comment: You could help people make a lot fewer guesses if you spelled out the timestamp format of those ~17 digits...

Comment: If it's YYmmddHHMMSS, then I don't understand how 181109 means 11-Nov-2018...?

Comment: "iso" order (YYMMDD) with two digits for the year...

Comment: looks like a mis-speak: should be "9th Nov 2018"'

Answer (score 1):

With bash, you can do this:

```
# the set-up
touch 20029181109173105_MAN_TDR.PLU 20029181109185001_MAN_TDR.PLU 20029181109185301_MAN_TDR.PLU 20029181109185601_MAN_TDR.PLU 20029181109185901_MAN_TDR.PLU

current=181109180000    # this would be `current=$(date "+%y%m%d%H%M%S")`

# the pay-off
for f in *PLU; do 
    if [[ $f =~ ^.....([0-9]{12}) ]] && [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} -gt "$current" ]]; then 
        echo "$f"
    fi
done
```

```
20029181109185001_MAN_TDR.PLU
20029181109185301_MAN_TDR.PLU
20029181109185601_MAN_TDR.PLU
20029181109185901_MAN_TDR.PLU
```